# Yaml key-value data is not parsing correctly in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Data extracted from one method is not getting parsed correctly when called in other.

```
class AppTool:
 def __init__(self, local_ip=None, host_ip=None, interval=None, transfer=None, bandwidth=None, app_results=None):
     self.local_ip = local_ip
     self.host_ip = host_ip
     self.interval = interval
     self.transfer = transfer
     self.bandwidth = bandwidth
     self.app_results = app_results if app_results is not None else {}

 @staticmethod
 def extract_information(output):
     local_ip_match = re.search(r'local (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', output)
     host_ip_match = re.search(r'Connecting to host (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', output)
     receiver_line_match = re.search(
         r'([\d.]+-[\d.]+)\s+sec\s+([\d.]+\s+\w?Bytes)\s+([\d.]+\s+\w?bits/sec)\s+receiver', output)
     if local_ip_match and host_ip_match and receiver_line_match:
         local_ip = local_ip_match.group(1)
         host_ip = host_ip_match.group(1)
         interval, transfer, bandwidth = receiver_line_match.groups()
         print("Extracted Information - local_ip", local_ip)
         print("Extracted Information - host_ip", host_ip)
         print("Extracted Information - interval", interval)
         print("Extracted Information - transfer", transfer)
         print("Extracted Information - bandwidth", bandwidth)
         return AppTool(local_ip, host_ip, interval, transfer, bandwidth)
     else:
         return None
```

The key's are parsing the correct value in the above method. But when this is called in the below method, it is taking incorrect values

```
 @staticmethod
 def create_config_map_manifest(extracted_info, app_results=None):
     data = {
         "local_IP": extracted_info.local_ip,
         "host_IP": extracted_info.host_ip,
         "interval": extracted_info.interval,
         "transfer": extracted_info.transfer,
         "bandwidth": extracted_info.bandwidth,
     }
     if app_results:
         data["app_results"] = app_results
     config_map_manifest = yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False)
     print("ConfigMap Data:", config_map_manifest)
     return data
```

On executing the code, the output is as shown below. The values extracted from extracted_information is not getting set correctly in create_config_map_manifest(). There is a mismatch

```
 Extracted Information - local_ip 10.122.1.159
 Extracted Information - host_ip 10.122.1.150
 Extracted Information - interval 0.00-5.02
 Extracted Information - transfer 10.8 GBytes
 Extracted Information - bandwidth 18.4 Gbits/sec
 -------------------------------
 ConfigMap Data: bandwidth: null
 host_IP: 0.00-5.02
 interval: 10.8 GBytes
 local_IP: 10.122.1.150
 transfer: 18.4 Gbits/sec
```

How to preserve the yaml key-value and it's order when called into other method?

Comment: Can you post code for `AppTool`?

Comment: @enzo I have updated it in the question.

Comment: which yaml library are you using?

Comment: @Anentropic I am using import yaml

Comment: `yaml` isn't built into python, did you `pip install pyyaml` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the `extracted_info` object is an instance of your class `AppTool`. The first thing I notice is you are passing in positional arguments to a function where all your parameters are keyword arguments, and that the resulting mismatch is shifted 1 value down. So `host_ip` becomes `local_ip`, `interval` becomes `host_ip`, etc. I would try returning your `AppTool` object with the following instantiation instead:

`return AppTool(local_ip=local_ip, host_ip=host_ip, interval=interval, transfer=transfer, bandwidth=bandwidth)`